# How can I map multiple sub-domains with a single A-Record?

Tags: domain, subdomain, ip-address, cname-record, a-record

lets assume I have the subdomains:

```
a.sheehan.com
b.sheehan.com
c.sheehan.com
```

i want to map them respectively to

```
haha.com
lala.com
baba.com
```

How can I have

```
a.sheehan.com map to haha.com
b.sheehan.com map to lala.com
c.sheehan.com map to baba.com
```

With a single A-Record or CNAME?

Comment: one of them must first exist as an A record in first place so `haha.com IN A someip` should exist so you can map anything to it afaik. After that you can simple have `a.sheehan.com IN CNAME haha.com.` perhaps you want to elaborate more your question.

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: with only a single record? only if they all have the same address, in which you can use a wildcard: *.sheehan.com IN A 1.2.3.4

Comment: your update has no meaning at all, still the same thing as to what you explainned and there is no way to acomplish it as i said above. Even if u use a wildcard unless all your 3 domains are in the same ip and you use mod_rewrite to map the subdomain to the correct place you won't be able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

First off, `A` records only point to IP addresses, so that option is right out, as your question is phrased.  (People loosely speak about an A record pointing to the canonical hostname of its referent, but it actually only points to the IP.)

For `CNAME` records, again, no: each maps from one alias name to one canonical name.  The only way you could do this, as jocmeau mentioned above, is a wildcard mapping them all to the same canonical name.

Perhaps you could expand your question to explain why you'd want to do this anyhow?